# Cassandra cpp-driver throwing error but able to connect with the cluster

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to connect the cassandra cpp-driver with 2 node cassandra cluster. It is throwing some error, but able to retrieve the keyspace names.

> 1430309809.995 [ERROR] (src/connection.cpp:413:static void cass::Connection::on_connect(cass::Connector*)): Connect error
>   'connection refused' on host 192.168.1.5
>
> 1430309809.995 [ERROR] (src/connection.cpp:651:void cass::Connection::notify_error(const string&)): Host 192.168.1.5 had
>   the following error on startup: 'Unable to connect'

`keyspace_name: 'mytest'`

`keyspace_name: 'system_traces'`

`keyspace_name: 'system'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your host 192.168.1.5 is not configured to accept the external connections but your driver is able to connect to the second node in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it. My bad, i had set the broadcast_rpc_address to the client ip, that's the reason i got such an error. Now i changed the broadcast_rpc_address to the ip of the same machine. It works fine now.